# What is practical use of list in createDataPartition

Tags: r, r-caret

Can someone please help me to understand practical use of list in createDataPartition, caret package

as per documentation, 
logical - should the results be in a list (TRUE) or a matrix with the number of rows equal to floor(p * length(y)) and times columns.

Comment: It's easy to `lapply` across bootstrap resamples in a list. They can also hold other data together with the resample indices, which a matrix can't.

Answer (score 1):

When used by `train` to do leave-group-out-cross-validation aka Monte Carlo CV. Also, what alistaire said.